# SQL Server remove trailing characters from column names

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with columns that contain trailing hash symbols:

```
SELECT * Table

Id DisplayName_55270A70 OSVersion_66DD9B43
1  NURAPP001            Windows Server 2008
```

The table schema appears to be unique for each installation of the tool that generated this schema. I'd like to create a query, without resorting to stored procedures, that would produce columns without hash symbols:

```
Id DisplayName          OSVersion
1  NURAPP001            Windows Server 2008
```

I'm able to product a comma-separated list of columns with the following query, but I don't know enough about SQL server to convert that into an executable query:

```
SELECT REPLACE(
(SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS 'data()'
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME='MTV_OperatingSystem' 
 ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
 FOR XML PATH(''))
,' ',', ')
```

Credit due: http://www.sql-ex.com/help/select20.php

Comment: Do any of your columns have underscores in their name (besides at the start of the hash)?

Comment: If the trailing characters are always preceded by an underscore (`_`) it's probably possible, as long as there are no underscores in the column names that you want to keep. You will probably need the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` system view.

Comment: Yes, all columns in the table follow the same convention. Hash at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create and execute a query with [EXECUTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-MX/library/ms188332.aspx), like this:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @cols = REPLACE(
(SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS 'data()'
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME='BankAcctInfo' 
 ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
 FOR XML PATH(''))
,' ',', ')

DECLARE @EXEC NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @EXEC = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' FROM YOURTABLENAME'

EXEC(@EXEC)
```

Comment: Thank you, @thepirat000. Unfortunately, the query is called from Java over JDBC so I cannot define local variable and execute stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

Without changing the existing schema; instead of using `*` what if you specify the column name explicitly specifying a `table alias` for the columns like

```
select Id,
DisplayName_55270A70 as DisplayName,
OSVersion_66DD9B43 as OSVersion
from mytable;
```

If you would like not typing it again, consider creating a `view`(a stored query) for the same like

```
create view myview 
as
select Id,
DisplayName_55270A70 as DisplayName,
OSVersion_66DD9B43 as OSVersion
from mytable;
```

Then next run, you can just do a `select * from myview`

Comment: Rahul, as I mentioned, the schema of this table varies from instance to instance. To illustrate:

Rahul, as I mentioned, the schema of this table varies from instance to instance. To illustrate:

Instance 1:
    Id DisplayName_55270A70 OSVersion_66DD9B43

Instance2:
    Id DisplayName_55270BBB OSVersion_66DD9CCC

If I knew column names ahead of time, I would just use aliases directly in the query SELECT  DisplayName_55270BBB AS DisplayName.

Comment: That's a strange thing. In that case, you will have to query from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and modify the column names accordingly (or) create a auxilary table with the modified column names.

Comment: Yes, it's a Microsoft product called System Center Operations Manager. MTV_OperatingSystem and other views are all designed like that.